# Showing or hiding div elements while waiting for a value from another site

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In PHP, is it possible to use conditions that will display either one of two div elements? My pseudocode:

```
//in Site 1
$tokenFromSite1 = 'xxx';
$tokenFromSite2 = '';
while($tokenFromSite1 != $tokenFromSite2){
    //show div containing Connect button;
    clickConnect(); //includes $tokenFromSite1 value as URL param "token" and opens a new tab to Site 2
        //in Site 2
        //gets $tokenFromSite1 value and opens a URL containing this value as param "token" and redirects to site 1
    //back to Site 1
    $tokenFromSite2 = //GET value of param "token"
}
//div containing Connect button disappears and shows a div that says "Connected"
```

I am not sure if my logic is correct, and how exactly is Site 1 going to "wait" for the token value from Site 2. Also, how do I hide/show div elements?

Comment: Your question is super unclear.

Comment: How are you getting this token? You can use ajax

Comment: To hide and show divs/buttons while using only PHP is not possible. You will need javaScript/ajax to get this done.

Comment: @Pratikshya, thanks. How do I show div element after clicking a button then make that button disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. PHP is compiled server side. It will run the full script and then output the results. In order to achieve what you want you will need a jQuery code that uses AJAX. Because it's a client side script it can interact with the user's screen after the page is loaded.